# How to find the $LU$ representation of a non-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I have a $3\times4$ matrix $A$, and I have to find matrices $L$ and $U$, such, that $A=LU$. But the problem is that the matrix is not symmetric, and I get a lot of variables. Any methods to do this?

[Here's also the picture of what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPdXO.jpg)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, lower and upper triangular. That's what I knew too, but I got this question from MIT open source final exams.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Here's the test, it's the first question: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/b799045edd80df18879088bcf872b214_MIT18_06S10_Final_Exam.pdf

Comment: Your attempt is not that bad. Then equating $A-LU$ to zero, you get a set of $12$ equations, in $15$ unknowns. With the additional condition $l_{11}=l_{22}=l_{33}=1$, you can easily solve the system (just write it, and solve the equations in one unknowns, replacing the values found in the remaining equation, until you are done).

Comment: @TatevBaghdasaryan See [here](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/lu-decomposition-calculator/?i=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B2%2C4%2C1%2C4%5D%2C%5B3%2C6%2C3%2C9%5D%5D).